# Replacing html page text by using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple javascript code which replaces the page content....by contents of another file(test2.html)

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("[href='#']").click(function() {
        function getcontent(url, id) {
            $("#id").load("url");
        }
    });
});
```

Now am using

```
<div id = "content">                 
<p> REPLACE </p>
</div>
<a href="#" onClick="getcontent('test2.html', 'content')">click here</a>
```

So now on clicking `click here` `REPLACE` should be replaced by content of `test2.html`...but its not happening...
I have included the required jquery.js file in my script..

Answer (score 1):

No, this won't work. `getcontent` is a function defined in a particular scope -- that of the click handler callback function. It is not accessible in the global scope -- the scope that the `onClick` method receives.

You should use a genuine click handler, perhaps setting data using data attributes:

```
$('[href="#"]').click(function() {
    $('#' + $(this).data('id')).load($(this).data('url'));
});
```

Using the following HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-url="test2.html" data-id="content">click here</a>
```

Comment: its not working if u can plz take a look at my complete code... [link](http://pastebin.com/ysvLB91H)

Comment: Does the HTTP request happen? Have a look with a network monitor, e.g. Firebug or Chrome console

Comment: my chrome console showing nothing and my Python server says ::code 404, message File not found "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404-

Answer (score 1):

You have a weird setup. The function `getcontent` is not defined in global scope, it cannot be found by the `onclick` event handler in the HTML. There are other issues as well.

I suggest something like:

```
<a href="#content" rel="test2.html">click here</a>
```

and

```
$(function(){
    $("a[href^='#']").click(function(){
        $(this.href).load(this.rel);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#' + id).load(url);
```

In your current method above, you are passing string literals, not the variables themselves.

Comment: That will not work. `getcontent` is not defined in global scope.

Comment: @Felix : how to define it in global scope

Comment: @Ran: This is not the only issue. Have a look at @lonesomeday's or my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be misunderstanding what certain parts of your code are doing.  Also, I'd recommend giving your href a real id to make things easier.  You don't need to use the jQuery 'click' method and ALSO assign an onclick handler inline in the HTML.

Try this instead:

```
<div id = "content">                 
   <p> REPLACE </p>
</div>
<a id="clickThis" href="#">click here</a>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#clickThis').click(function() {
       $('#content').load('test2.html');
    });
});
```

Your code with some comments:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // this will assign a click handler, you don't need an 'onclick'
    // attribute on the anchor tag also
    $("[href='#']").click(function() {
        // but what does your click handler do?
        // It defines a function that is never called.
        function getcontent(url, id) {
            $("#id").load("url");
        }
    });
});
```